# Function in React Component is not defined with rule no-undef Eslint

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint

When I run eslint in my project it shows error like:

```
error  'startCountDown' is not defined
```

this is my class code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Text, ScaleSize, Colors } from '@momo-platform/component-kits';
import Localization from '@localization';
import themes from '@themes';

class CountDownBody extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            countDown: this.props.countDown,
        };
        this._mounted = true;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.startCountDown();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._mounted = false;
    }

    startCountDown = () => {
        const { countDown } = this.state;
        if (countDown > 0 && this._mounted) {
            this.setState({ countDown: countDown - 1 });
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.startCountDown();
            }, 1000);
        } else if (this._mounted) {
            this.props.onClose && this.props.onClose();
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { countDown } = this.state;
        const { message } = this.props;

        let msg = '';
        if (message) {
            msg = message.replace('%second%', countDown);
        } else {
            let minutes = Math.floor(countDown / 60);
            minutes = minutes >= 10 ? minutes : `0${minutes}`;
            let seconds = countDown % 60;
            seconds = seconds >= 10 ? seconds : `0${seconds}`;

            msg =
                countDown < 60
                    ? Localization.messagePendingLockSecond.replace('%second%', countDown)
                    : Localization.messagePendingLock.replace('%second%', `${minutes}:${seconds}`);
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{msg}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        paddingTop: themes.layout_20,
        paddingHorizontal: themes.layout_20,
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: ScaleSize(16),
        color: Colors.text_color,
    },
});

export default CountDownBody;
```

This eslint config:

```
module.exports = {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    root: true,
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 7,
        ecmaFeatures: {
            impliedStrict: true,
            jsx: true,
            experimentalObjectRestSpread: true,
        },
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    env: {
        node: true,
        es6: true,
    },
    plugins: ['@momo-platform/momo'],
    extends: ['@react-native-community', 'plugin:@momo-platform/momo/all'],
    rules: {
        'no-undef': 2,
        'no-control-regex': 0,
        semi: 0,
        'jsx-quotes': 0,
        'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 0,
        curly: 0,
        'no-catch-shadow': 0,
        'no-extra-boolean-cast': 0,
        'no-bitwise': 0,
        'no-shadow': 0,
        'react-native/no-inline-styles': 0,
    },
    globals: { _: true, __DEV__: true, alert: true, fetch: true, fs: true },
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ['*.js', '*.jsx'],
            rules: {
                '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

Comment: I use class component

Comment: Change your arrow function to a standard function def: `startCountDown() {`.

Comment: Why must change arrow function to a standard function?

Comment: Because arrow functions have no context for `this`. [Refrence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Do you know other solutions like config eslint to resolve this problem?

Comment: The only way is to set Babel to transpile into ES2017, or use `this.startCountDown = () => { }`.